# Print div is not working in chrome and not taking the style as the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am using this 
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-ask-ben-print-part-of-a-web-page-with-jquery.htm

Using this jquery to print a div, but its not working in chrome, also it need the style to be inernal in the same page and cannot use the external css.

```
<html>
<head>
// code
        <link rel="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootssstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.print.js.js"></script>

       <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            // Hook up the print link.
            $("#print_div").click(function(){
                alert("asd");
                // Print the DIV.
                    $( ".printable" ).print();
                    // Cancel click event.
                    return( false );
                });
            });

        </script>
      <head>  
      <body>

// code
<div class="container text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg print" id="print_div" >Print</a>
</div>
   <div class="printable">
       // section that need to be printed
       // images, css form 
       // code
</div>
<body>
    </html>
```

Any better suggestions any way where we can integrate this
https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

```
if (opt.importCSS) $("link[rel=stylesheet]").each(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                if (href) {
                    var media = $(this).attr("media") || "all";
                    $doc.find("head").append("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + href + "' media='" + media + "'>")
                }
            });
```

Comment: If possible, can describe _"need the style to be in the same page and cannot use the imported css."_ ? What is url of `href` for `link` element ? Which specific `style`s to be applied to `.printable` `div`? Note, `.printable` class not appear within `html` at OP ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

*"use that bootstrap one, its same from its cdn.. "* Try http://jsfiddle.net/dLk2kwx9/7 . https protocol request for `maxcdn` returned `403 FORBIDDEN` error . Try substituting `http` protocol for `https` protocol at `link` and `script` elements `href` and `src` attributes , respectively. Applied styles should be reflected at `.container` , `.btn` elements.

---

Note, `.printable` class not appear within `html` at OP ? Not certain about which specific styles to be applied at `printable` ? , `href` of `link` element referenced at closing of Question ? Tried at chrome 37

Try

html

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg print" id="print_div">Print</a>
</div>
<!-- added `printable` class to `div` to be be printed -->
<div class="printable">
       stuff to print
</div>
```

css

```
/* `printable` styles to be applied before print, removed after print */
.printstyle {    
    font-size : 36px;
}
```

js

```
$(function() {
    $(".print").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
        $("body *:not(.printable)").hide(function() {
          $(".printable").addClass("printstyle");
            // $("head").append("<link>", {
            // "href":"url"
            // "rel":"stylesheet"
            // });
            window.print()
        }).promise().done(function(el) {
          $(".printable").removeClass("printstyle");  
          el.show()
        });
    })
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/dLk2kwx9/

Comment: Its blocking other jquery event on the page and not taking the external css still.

Comment: Trying to do the same as I am using this http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-ask-ben-print-part-of-a-web-page-with-jquery.htm but its not working for external css and chrome..

Comment: If possible, can post external css url ? , external css text ?

Comment: did you got any solution.. or should I use some php print options like mpdf or html2pdf

Comment: u are using the css on the same page, that will work but when you load the content in the print external css won't reflect..

Comment: @atjoshi Requirement to apply `css` to `.printable` element ? Does `bootstrap` css contain style properties for elements having class `printable` ? Which specific style properties should be set for `.printable` to achieve requirement ? Perhaps not interpreting Question correctly ? If possible can describe details of requirement ? Thanks

Comment: I already updated the ques after the first comment, it has code, images, css written as comment